# href url for my stylesheets and other resources

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc, directory

I am Working on a Spring MVC project, and while building the landing page(home.jsp), I am confused as to how to write the URL(in href tag) of my css Stylesheets and othe resources(like images, fonts, scripts, etc).
I am in views directory(working in home.jsp) and want to access the resources directory. 
This is my directory structure-- https://i.stack.imgur.com/I56dT.jpg

I have tried the following 3, but nothing seems to work.:

```
<link href=".../resources/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet">

<link href="../../resources/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet">

<link href="../resources/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet">
```

Any help will be immense. Thanks in advance! Have a good day!

Comment: I think your code is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help @abiudrn, this works for me(jstl):

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
```

And, in the dispatcher servlet:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To include CSS or JS in a JSP page, you can use JSTL tag `c:url`

Here, Try this:

```
<link href="<c:url value="../resources/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />" 
rel="stylesheet">
```

You can also use the Spring tag `spring:url` for example:

```
<spring:url value="../resources/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" 
var="mainCss" />
```

If you don't like all the above you can use the page context variable for example:

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}../resources/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" >
```

Comment: I understand I can use jstl tags, but I really want to know about a simpler option. like directory url.

Comment: I have made changes. Please check.